# WIC/WPF: System.GPS.Longitude and System.GPS.Latitude always return NULL (via BitmapMetadata)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, wic

Has anyone successfully read GPS data using WPFs class `BitmapMetadata` which internally uses WIC (Windows Imaging Component)?

I have an image where both Windows (8.1) Explorer and external tools like XnView show GPS coordinates.

I try to extract these data using the class `BitmapMetadata` which is available via property `Metadata` of class `BitmapFrame`:

```
var md = (BitmapMetdata)extractedFrame.Metadata;
var altitude = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Altitude");
var altitudeProxy = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Altitude.Proxy");
var altitudeRef = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.AltitudeRef");
var longitude = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Longitude");
var longitudeProxy = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Longitude.Proxy");
var longitudeRef = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.LongitudeRef");
var latitude = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Latitude");
var latitudeProxy = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.Latitude.Proxy");
var latitudeRef = md.GetQuery("System.GPS.LatitudeRef");
```

Results of `altitude` (System.Double), `altitudeRef` (System.Byte), `longitudeRef` (System.String) and `latitudeRef` (System.String) are all ok and retrieve reasonable data ("510.70", "0", "N", "E").

`longitude` and `latitude` should be arrays of System.Double **but they are always NULL**.

The results using the ".Proxy" suffixes return strange String data of which I am not shure how they are to be parsed and if they are culture invariant or not: The MSDN docs tell something different, nothing about strings; but at least there would be "valid" data for Longitude and Latitude there.

Is it a bug or my fault in missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the code here to access the latitude and longitude: http://khason.net/blog/how-to-read-gps-metadata-from-image/
It doesn't handle the N,S,E,W +/- part though. So you will have to use the LongitudeRef and LatitudeRef above to figure out whether to change the sign on your coordinates. 
Basically:

```
JpegBitmapDecoder decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
BitmapMetadata meta = (BitmapMetadata)decoder.Frames[0].Metadata;
ulong[] latitude    = meta.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/gps/subifd:{ulong=2}") as ulong[];
ulong[] longitude   = meta.GetQuery("/app1/ifd/gps/subifd:{ulong=4}") as ulong[];
double lat          = ConvertCoordinate(latitude);
double longit       = ConvertCoordinate(longitude);

static double ConvertCoordinate(ulong[] coordinates)
{
    int lDash   = (int)(coordinates[0] - ((ulong)0x100000000));
    int lF      = (int)(coordinates[1] - ((ulong)0x100000000));
    double lR   = ((double)(coordinates[2] - ((ulong)0x6400000000))) / 100;
    double tRes = (lDash + (((double)lF) / 60)) + (lR / 3600);
    return (Math.Floor((double)(tRes * 1000000)) / 1000000);
}
```

**EDIT** the above only worked for older EXIF formats. Newer formats had more digits on the coordinates so they were converted incorrectly. I had to update Convert Coordinates to this:

```
static double ConvertCoordinate(ulong[] coordinates)
{
    if (coordinates == null)
        return 0;

    double degrees = ConvertToUnsignedRational( coordinates[ 0 ] ); 
    double minutes = ConvertToUnsignedRational( coordinates[ 1 ] ); 
    double seconds = ConvertToUnsignedRational( coordinates[ 2 ] ); 
    return degrees + (minutes / 60.0) + (seconds / 3600); 

}
static double ConvertToUnsignedRational( ulong value ) 
{ 
    return (value & 0xFFFFFFFFL) / (double) ((value & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000L) >> 32); 
}
```

Comment: @StefanFalk it's an answer, not a question. If you are the downvoter I suggest to revert this since the answer does return reasonable values.

Comment: @springy76 I'm sorry! I did that mistake while reviewing and thought this was an actual question! I will undo my downvote but I have to wait until her accepts my edit since SO has locked my vote decision until then.

Comment: BTW: There a 2 additional keys for `meta.GetQuery()` which also can return `ulong[]` :  "/xmp/exif:GPSLatitude" and "/xmp/exif:GPSLongitude"

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late to answer, but the .Proxy values have the following format:

```
MetaDataValue   "16,0.4965000000000145E"    object {string}
```

means 16 degrees, 0.49 minutes. So you just have to convert it to minutes AND seconds.